# Unity: Texture glitches on Build

Tags: unity, materials, build-process

I'm getting the most horrible glitches on multiple materials and objects. In the Unity Editor everything is fine. When building individual scenes alone it is fine. But when I build all the scenes including main menu, things like this happen.

I have no idea what I should do in terms of diagnosis since it's fine when building the scene by itself. I've had similar, seemingly undiagnosifiable, encounters with unity builds.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's a thing with Unity, but, do you bust your VRAM size limit?

Comment: Im using 5/16GB. Same bug happens on lowest graphic settings. But doesn't happen when building individual scenes.